# Button selected effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I am new to react. I want to add class name "active-btn" on button click in to make button selected on button click. Here is my code

```
<div className="shop-page product-details">
      <div  className="product-info-tabs prod-tabs">
        <div className="container clearfix nav">
          <div className="nav-items nav-pills tab-btns" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <button className="nav-link nav-pills tab-btn " role="tab" value={1} onClick={(e)=> loadTab(e.target.value)} aria-selected="true">Car Service</button>
            <button className="nav-link nav-pills tab-btn" role="tab" value={2} onClick={(e)=> loadTab(e.target.value)} aria-selected="false">Denting & Painting</button>
            <button className="nav-link nav-pills tab-btn" role="tab" value={3} onClick={(e)=> loadTab(e.target.value)} aria-selected="false">Mechnical & Electrical Repair</button>
            <button className="nav-link nav-pills tab-btn" role="tab" value={4} onClick={(e)=> loadTab(e.target.value)} aria-selected="false">Add Ons</button></div></div></div></div>
```

I have tried classlist.add function

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of tab the user pressed.
you can use useState for this:

```
 const [activeTabName, setActiveTabName] = useState("tab1");
```

in the loadTab function you should then call setActiveTabName(tabName).

then check if the classname needs to be added with this piece of code

```
<button className={`nav-link nav-pills tab-btn ${activeTabName === "tab1" ? "active-btn" : ""}`}....
```

this post will help you in more detail:
https://www.andreasreiterer.at/dynamically-add-classes/